# how to automate the airplane mode in appium automation

Tags: appium

In my test, I've declare an `AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(completeURL), capabilities);`

but I didnt't get any defined method to perform setConnection operation with this driver declaration.
Please let me know how can I set my driver.setConnection to Airplane mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Toggle Airplane Mode](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/network/toggle-airplane-mode/).

// Java

```
driver.toggleAirplaneMode();
```

// JavaScript

```
driver.toggleAirplaneMode();
```

// Ruby

```
@driver.toggle_flight_mode
```

Comment: is there any way in JAVA for MobileElement

Comment: @buckalot according to appium documentation it supports Java http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/network/toggle-airplane-mode/
but I could not use it too.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in Appium version 1.15.1 You can easily change the airplane mode by performing click action on it. First open the notification panel.

```
((AndroidDriver<?>)driver).openNotifications();
```

use 1 sec delay

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

use the inspector to spy the airplane mode property, I have used the xpath for this.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath for airplane mode")).click();
```

and, close the notification panel after this.

```
((AndroidDriver<?>)driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.BACK));
```